# Issue with 'as' between Xcode versions

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm having the following code that compiles without issues on Xcode 6.2:

```
let rootViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as NoticiasTableViewController
```

If I tested it with Xcode 6.3 beta to prevent future issues I get the following error:

> Replace 'as' with 'as!'

If I replace `as` with `as!` as suggested, then Xcode 6.2 gave me an error:

```
let rootViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! NoticiasTableViewController
```

> Expected type after 'as'

So, in one of two versions of Xcode, I'm unable to compile the sources.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be compiled with both version.

```
let rootViewController = ( navigationController!.viewControllers[0] as? NoticiasTableViewController )!
```

Comment: If I use your code does not work. I replaced it, with `let rootViewController = ( navigationController.viewControllers[0] as? NoticiasTableViewController )!` (note that I removed an exclamation mark).

Answer (score 0):

Swift is still in an evolving phase. Xcode 6.3 already uses Swift 1.2 so if you want to use the new features of Swift 1.2 you have to use the beta version.